# g++ compile and link vs. build at once different outcome using Armadillo library

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am testing Armadillo library and wrote four cpp files to be build.
I am able to build them with one command:

```
g++ chol.cpp  conj_grad.cpp  main.cpp  special_mat.cpp -larmadillo -std=c++14 -o test
```

However, when I compile individual files first and them link, I'll encounter linking errors:

```
g++ -c -std=c++14 -g -O1 main.cpp -o main.o

g++ -c -std=c++14 -g -O1 chol.cpp -o chol.o

g++ -c -std=c++14 -g -O1 conj_grad.cpp -o conj_grad.o

g++ -c -std=c++14 -g -O1 special_mat.cpp -o special_mat.o

g++ -larmadillo  main.o chol.o conj_grad.o special_mat.o -o test
```

Error message:

```
main.o: In function `main':
/home/me/doc/study/numerical_optimization/chap5/main.cpp:71: undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'
main.o: In function `std::__detail::_Adaptor<std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 64ul, 312ul, 156ul, 31ul, 13043109905998158313ul, 29ul, 6148914691236517205ul, 17ul, 8202884508482404352ul, 37ul, 18444473444759240704ul, 43ul, 6364136223846793005ul>, double>::operator()()':
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/random.h:192: undefined reference to `arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'
main.o: In function `main':
/home/me/doc/study/numerical_optimization/chap5/main.cpp:71: undefined reference to `TLS init function for arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'
main.o: In function `std::__detail::_Adaptor<std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 64ul, 312ul, 156ul, 31ul, 13043109905998158313ul, 29ul, 6148914691236517205ul, 17ul, 8202884508482404352ul, 37ul, 18444473444759240704ul, 43ul, 6364136223846793005ul>, double>::operator()()':
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/random.h:192: undefined reference to `arma::arma_rng_cxx11_instance'
```

I've omitted more linking errors.

Why is that?  What is the difference between these two build approaches?  Thanks.

Comment: Try putting `-larmadillo` at the end of the command line: `g++ -o test main.o chol.o conj_grad.o special_mat.o  -larmadillo`

Comment: That solves my problem. Thank you!  I now remember the searching sequence of linker causes the problem.